# RMI+hibernate,how can client get generated id

Tags: java, hibernate, rmi

```
@Entity
public class Record implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@Cascade(value={CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
private List<Comment> commentList=new ArrayList<Comment>();

}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Comment implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(columnDefinition="text")
private String content;
}
```

I have a Record in my Client, and add SOME comments in the list. 
Use the RMI method: void update(Record reocord).
Then at the Server, hibernate save Comments with id=0 into database, and give a generated id.
How can I assign these IDs to Comments in the Client? If not, the other time I call update(Record reocord), Comments will be add twice. 
Maybe: Record update(Record reocord), but I think if Record have large data it's not wise.

Comment: Well, I finally choose to solve this by returning id of comment every time I add a new one.I'd better make a better design of database relation and architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue. If you are autogenerating the primary key (which can be mostly used for normalizing tables), Create a unique Id yourself based on the existing data. Do remember to override `hashcode` and `equals` for comparison purposes.